# Dynamics CRM - Register a plug-in when the user logs in

Tags: plugins, dynamics-crm, crm, microsoft-dynamics

I would like to fire an event when the user logs in to his account on Dynamics CRM ? Such as opening a Web App beside the CRM... Is This possible ? 
I know that I can write plug-in that allows to augment some business process such as account creation. Any advice will be appreciated !

Answer (score 5):

CRM does not expose a plugin message for "UserLogon/UserAccess" on which you can register a plugin.

What you could do though is enable [Audit User Access](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh547392.aspx) and register your plugin on `Create` of an audit entity and filter on the value in `AuditAction` (operation) and `User Access Via Web (64)` is the value you are looking for.

```
var entity = ((Entity)pluginExecutionContext.InputParameters["Target"]).ToEntity<Audit>();
if (entity.Operation.GetValueOrDefault() == 64)
{
   //logic here
}
```

Comment: Thanks you, I'll try it out and come back with my observation :)

Answer (score 1):

I think dynamicallyCRM gives a good idea, but if you are trying to open some website, plugin is not the option; it's meant to execute server side logic.

If all end users use the same homepage when login to CRM (let's say they are asked not to change it), you can set up a custom page as the homepage, and there you are able to add scripts to do whatever you want.