# Can I register a plug-in on the user login event in Dynamics CRM?

Tags: dynamics-crm, crm, dynamics-crm-online

I want to register a plug-in in Plugin Registration Tool when a user logs in to Dynamics CRM. For this I don't want to use Audit. I want to catch the login event directly.

If this is not possible, is there any log that is create in every login of the user.

Comment: I do not think you can capture that event, but if you have the auditing enabled then you can perhaps create a Microsoft Flow that is triggered when a record is created.  Specifically, when an audit record is created.  you can monitor "last seen" an you can tell if the user hasn't been seen in a while. -- not a bad problem though.  I will take a closer look.

Comment: Yes, but i don't want to use audit. Sorry, is there any other log that is created when the user logs in the CRM, so I can use this for tracking the logs of the user?

Comment: I have heard of others capturing that signal with JavaScript on the screen where your users "land" after their login.  I've never tried it though.

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40489646/dynamics-crm-register-a-plug-in-when-the-user-logs-in. What are you trying to do when this action occurs?

Comment: I want to get all the information from the user, like IP, Longitude, ISP, Latitude, browser ect. In other word I want to create a Geo Log Entity for every logs of the User. But for all of this, I don't want to use Audit, like is suggested in that question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

High level design of what I would do:

1. Make/identify a default dashboard for all users and keep a HTML web resource in there
2. Web resource can have a method to invoke `Xrm.WebApi.online.execute` for executing a Custom Action by passing parameter to include IP, Lat, Lon, Browser details. [Read more](https://www.inogic.com/blog/2019/01/execute-action-using-xrm-webapi-online-execute-in-dynamics-365-crm-v9-0/)
3. Register a plugin on Custom Action message to trigger and achieve what you want there

Answer (score 2):

As far as I know, No you cannot do so.
But CRM has provided few different ways where you can check which users are currently working/logged in.

1. Go to Settings--> System Settings--> Auditing and then you can enable audit user access. 
   [image]
2. Above will enable for all users and then you can see audit data as below.
   [image]

Ref for 1st option https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/emeadcrmsupport/2015/07/09/dynamics-crm-audit-user-access-data/

Now another way you can do so it visit url https://admin.powerplatform.microsoft.com/

Here go under analytics and then common data service. You wil get most of the info
[image]

Comment: Yes, but I don't want to use Audit. I want to try another way. Thanks!